# How to fix ruby error: sh: 1: make: not found

Tags: python, ruby, django, chef-infra, vagrant

I am working my way through a video tutorial at http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/introduction-and-launch/

I am working on win7 and using git-bash for my terminal. I have installed the latest virtualbox - 4.2.12 and the latest vagrant - 1.22.

I tried to run vagrant up and got:

```
  $ vagrant up
  Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
  [default] Setting the name of the VM...
  [default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
  [default] Creating shared folders metadata...
  [default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
  [default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
  [default] Forwarding ports...
  [default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
  [default] -- 8000 => 8888 (adapter 1)
  [default] Booting VM...
  [default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
  [default] VM booted and ready for use!
  [default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
  [default] Mounting shared folders...
  [default] -- /vagrant
  [default] -- /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
  [default] -- /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-2/cookbooks
  [default] Running provisioner: shell...
  [default] Running: inline script
  stdin: is not a tty
  ERROR:  Error installing chef:
          ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.      

          /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
  creating Makefile      

  make
  sh: 1: make: not found    


  Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0 for in
  spection.
  Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/ext/yajl/gem_make.out
  Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
  The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
  Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!      

      chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell && /tmp/vagrant-shell
```

When I do:

```
$ which make
```

I get:

```
/c/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/make
```

so it looks like make is in filepath

How can I fix this?

addendum: when I edit the vagrantfile to:

config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "curl -L https://opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash"

I get:

```
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 1: curl: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

The basebox you're using does not have the "build-essential" package installed by default, and it has a "[shell provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html)" that installs the Chef gem into the default Ruby environment. Chef has a dependency on the JSON RubyGem, which itself has C extensions that must be compiled. This is what is looking for `make`.

To resolve this issue, I'd recommend using Opscode's "omnibus" [full stack installer for Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/). This can be used by changing the shell provisioner line to:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "curl -L https://opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash"
```

Or, if your basebox doesn't have curl, use wget:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "wget -O https://opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash"
```

The `[install.sh][3]` script simply inspects the VM to determine what its platform is so it can retrieve the proper URL from an S3 bucket. If you prefer you can use the constructed URL to download the .deb file directly:

https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/11.04/x86_64/chef_11.4.4-2.ubuntu.11.04_amd64.deb

And then install it:

```
dpkg -i chef_11.4.4-2.ubuntu.11.04_amd64.deb
```

See the Vagrant documentation on [shell provisioners](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) to see how to write this as a small script.

Answer (score 0):

In which machine, did  you run `which make`? (host/guest).
Make sure guest(virtualbox) have a `make`.

https://github.com/scottmuc/vagrant-postgresql/issues/1#issuecomment-7798110

Answer (score 0):

If the OS doesn't have make pre-installed, and you still want to continue moving forward, you can do something along the lines of:

```
e = package "make" do
        action :nothing
end

e.run_action(:install)
```

which will install the make package at compile time, before any of your cookbooks try to use it.
You should put this in one of your recipes, preferably at the top, so it is clear to other readers what is happening.

Comment: Adam , I'm sorry , but I'm new to vagrant and chef. Can you explain where to put the code you have included? I am just trying to run the VM discussed in the - Bill

Comment: ... article ( missed a word )

Comment: I just re-read the question, along with the article and my suggestion won't be as easy a fix for your problem. You could 1)Get a VM with an upgraded version of Chef (you don't have to run the inline Chef upgrade) 2)Don't upgrade Chef if you don't need it, or 3)Upgrade Chef in an alternative way-> put the upgrade in a cookbook, and you could add any missing packages you need in this new cookbook. The easiest option is #2, but that could easily backfire if you do need an upgraded Chef version. If you have the time, I would suggest digging a bit deeper into Chef & Vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

It tured out, Thanks I had the wrong version of chef. I needed version 11.4.2 which is not the most recent. The most recent did not work for me . I went to

```
http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/
```

and downloaded and installed:

```
chef-client-11.4.2-1.windows.msi
```

and it worked after doing vagrant destroy, and following that with vagrant up.