# Error using curl from git-bash to install chef

Tags: git, chef-infra, git-bash

I am trying to use git-bash in win 7 to use the chef omnibus installer. I tried the following:

```
$ curl -L https://opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6506  100  6506    0     0   5957      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  6834
Unable to determine platform version!
Please file a bug report at http://tickets.opscode.com
Project: Chef
Component: Packages
Label: Omnibus
Version:

Please detail your operating system type, version and any other relevant details
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You might potentially be able to modify the install.sh and then run it locally, or place it on a server of your own and execute  it in a similar fashion, but it will need to be modified for the platform and version at the very least.  However, according to:

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Fast+Start+Guide+for+Windows

It looks like you can do this following a different method, it does state the following:

> **Operating System** Chef runs on many popular Unix and Linux platforms as well as Mac OSX and Windows. We will describe how to set
>   up using Windows 2008 R2 as a workstation and a client, but these are
>   general directions that will also apply to Windows 7. These directions
>   are known to not work for Windows Server 2003 or on systems that have
>   spaces in the %HOMEPATH%. For instructions on these, see the
>   workstation installation page or the client installation page for
>   Windows.

I assume that possibly the reason you are looking to execute it with bash is to get a more automated install.  If the install script is too difficult to modify you could potentially use something more windows-oriented to automate the install according to  the guidelines in that link.

By the way, I tried using the same method as you did and received the same message, looking at install.sh you have these lines:

```
machine=$(echo -e `uname -m`)

# Retrieve Platform and Platform Version
if [ -f "/etc/lsb-release" ] && grep -q DISTRIB_ID /etc/lsb-release;
then
  platform=$(grep DISTRIB_ID /etc/lsb-release | cut -d "=" -f 2 | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
  platform_version=$(grep DISTRIB_RELEASE /etc/lsb-release | cut -d "=" -f 2)
elif [ -f "/etc/debian_version" ];
then
  platform="debian"
  platform_version=$(echo -e `cat /etc/debian_version`)
elif [ -f "/etc/redhat-release" ];
then
  platform=$(sed 's/^\(.\+\) release.*/\1/' /etc/redhat-release | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
  platform_version=$(sed 's/^.\+ release \([.0-9]\+\).*/\1/' /etc/redhat-release)

  # If /etc/redhat-release exists, we act like RHEL by default
  if [ "$platform" = "fedora" ];
  then
    # Change platform version for use below.
    platform_version="6.0"
  fi
  platform="el"
elif [ -f "/etc/system-release" ];
then
  platform=$(sed 's/^\(.\+\) release.\+/\1/' /etc/system-release | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
  platform_version=$(sed 's/^.\+ release \([.0-9]\+\).*/\1/' /etc/system-release | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
  # amazon is built off of fedora, so act like RHEL
  if [ "$platform" = "amazon linux ami" ];
  then
    platform="el"
    platform_version="6.0"
  fi
# Apple OS X
elif [ -f "/usr/bin/sw_vers" ];
then
  platform="mac_os_x"
  # Matching the tab-space with sed is error-prone
  platform_version=$(sw_vers | awk '/^ProductVersion:/ { print $2 }')

  major_version=$(echo $platform_version | cut -d. -f1,2)
  case $major_version in
    "10.6") platform_version="10.6" ;;
    "10.7") platform_version="10.7" ;;
    "10.8") platform_version="10.7" ;;
    *) echo "No builds for platform: $major_version"
       report_bug
       exit 1
       ;;
  esac

  # x86_64 Apple hardware often runs 32-bit kernels (see OHAI-63)
  x86_64=$(sysctl -n hw.optional.x86_64)
  if [ $x86_64 -eq 1 ]; then
    machine="x86_64"
  fi
elif [ -f "/etc/release" ];
then
  platform="solaris2"
  machine=$(/usr/bin/uname -p)
  platform_version=$(/usr/bin/uname -r)
elif [ -f "/etc/SuSE-release" ];
then
  if grep -q 'Enterprise' /etc/SuSE-release;
  then
      platform="sles"
      platform_version=$(awk '/^VERSION/ {V = $3}; /^PATCHLEVEL/ {P = $3}; END {print V "." P}' /etc/SuSE-release)
  else
      platform="suse"
      platform_version=$(awk '/^VERSION =/ { print $3 }' /etc/SuSE-release)
  fi
fi

platform="windows"

if [ "x$platform" = "x" ];
then
  echo "Unable to determine platform version!"
  report_bug
  exit 1
fi

# Mangle $platform_version to pull the correct build
# for various platforms
major_version=$(echo $platform_version | cut -d. -f1)
case $platform in
  "el")
    case $major_version in
      "5") platform_version="5" ;;
      "6") platform_version="6" ;;
    esac
    ;;
  "debian")
    case $major_version in
      "5") platform_version="6";;
      "6") platform_version="6";;
    esac
    ;;
esac

if [ "x$platform_version" = "x" ];
then
  echo "Unable to determine platform version!"
  report_bug
  exit 1
fi

if [ $use_shell = 1 ];
then
  shell_filename
else
  case $platform in
    "ubuntu") deb_filename ;;
    "debian") deb_filename ;;
    "el") rpm_filename ;;
    "suse") rpm_filename ;;
    "sles") rpm_filename ;;
    "fedora") rpm_filename ;;
    "solaris2") svr4_filename ;;
    *) shell_filename ;;
  esac
fi

echo "Downloading Chef $version for ${platform}..."

url="https://opscode.com/chef/download?v=${version}&prerelease=${prerelease}&p=${platform}&pv=${platform_version}&m=${machine}"
```

and the last line there, on line 199 of that install.sh script:

```
https://opscode.com/chef/download?v=${version}&prerelease=${prerelease}&p=${platform}&pv=${platform_version}&m=${machine}
```

I could not find a url that would work for windows 7 yet but if there is one, you can plug in the details there and it should at least be able to begin the install.

Comment: Your welcome.  I looked a little further and it does appear they are all MSI's so for windows you can go here too where I'd probably use 2008 as substitute for win7:  http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/

Comment: And you can probably automate that by pushing out to the systems that need chef and then  running there with msiexec /i path/yourchef.msi or something along those lines.

Comment: I will follow investigate your detailed answer further. Could I also ask you to check out: taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119003/how-to-fix-ruby-error-sh-1-make-not-found. This was my original question. The current question is a follow up

Comment: Took a quick glance, I see so it appears you have virtualbox with Windows7 as guest, and that's where the chef issue comes in.  If I get some time in the evening this week I'll take a more detailed look.

Comment: Thanks , I eventually figured it out. I had the wrong version of chef. I needed version 11.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use the `install.sh` script on Windows. Chef publishes Windows packages as an MSI.